# stream and filter not working as expected

Tags: java

To explain it shortly, a list of candidates are available in the **candidateMap**.

Initially it looked like this:

```
if (autoLink &&
        // original line
        candidateMap.size() == 1 &&
        candidateMap.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue() >= dnbHome.getAutolinkThreshold()) {
            .......
```

So if the **candidateMap** has 1 candidate, then do something.

I have changed it so that it could have multiple candidates, but if there is exactly 1 equal or above the threshold, then it should do something.

```
if (autoLink &&
        // new line not working as intended
        candidateMap.entrySet().stream().filter(m -> m.getValue() >= dnbHome.getAutolinkThreshold()).count() == 1 &&
        candidateMap.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue() >= dnbHome.getAutolinkThreshold()) {

    customer.setDnbOrganization(candidateMap.entrySet().iterator().next().getKey());
    customer.setOrganizationCandidates(Collections.emptyMap()); // ensure that any links to candidates are removed
    return true;

} else {
    customer.setOrganizationCandidates(candidateMap);
    return false;
}
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work. Is it me who doesn't understand the stream and filter correctly?

If **candidateMap** contains two candidates with a value 8 and 10, and **autolinkthreshold** is 9, then it should be good enough after the code change, but it isn't.

Comment: You check if there is 1 entry with a value above the threshold, and check if the first entry has a value above the threshold. So with 8 and 10 and a threshold of 9 this isn't the case.

Comment: ^ I'm not sure why you left the third condition in there, but I think it's throwing you off.

Comment: 3rd line seem redundant, yes

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is that the iteration order of `entrySet().stream()` and `entrySet().iterator()` aren't guaranteed to be consistent. Instead of iterating `candidateMap` three times inside an `if` condition, why don't you do it before?

```
Optional<String> org = candidateMap.entrySet()
  .stream()
  .findFirst(m -> m.getValue() >= dnbHome.getAutolinkThreshold())
  .map(Map.Entry::getKey);

if (autolink && org.isPresent()) {}
```